# How transfer data between 2 software in different computers

Tags: c#, .net, transfer

I am developing two Csharp programs and I need to transfer data of multiple tables in a program to another one which could be in a different computer with no internet connection.

What is the best method for transferring data?

EDIT (from comments):

> the computers does not have internet connection, but usb-flash-drive,
>   network, etc. are still available –

Comment: Do you have any network? WiFi, Ethernet, Bluethooth, etc... ?

Comment: [Sneakernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sneakernet)?

Comment: How do you expect to do it without a internet connection? By Magic? Are the computers connected via LAN?

Comment: USB flash drive is still an efficient way.

Comment: the computers does not have internet connection, but usb-flash-drive, network, etc. are still available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really **tables**, the easiest way to go is insert the data in a SQlite Database and simply transport the file (Via netweork, USB-Stick, Punchcard, typing the hex, whatever)

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have an internetconnection, i would Seriealize data to xml and move it on a usb-flash-drive.

One [way of doing it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx) using annotated classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets for exchanging data between programs in same computers as well as programs in different computers. For that you need to create socket program's  ( a message passing infrastructure).

If you are too lazy you can use the open source message passing implementations like

http://www.rabbitmq.com/ ( A popular one)

For details go through

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue

Answer (score 0):

If you have a printer and a scanner you could print the table from one computer and scan in on the other. This will require you to have have an OCR algo to recognize the text from an image.
Another optimization you could apply on this is that you could actually place a monitor from the first computer onto the scanner directly and scan the content of the monitor.